# How to get value from other page?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have to get value from one page to another and depending on that some some divs should display.I am usingjquery mobiles.

This is the link to jsfiddle:[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PriyankaPatil/MKV72/)

### HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
<div data-role="header">
        <h1>Click</h1>

</div>
<!-- /header -->
   <div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p> <a data-role="button" href="#foo" class="clicko" id="1">Venta</a>
   <a data-role="button" href="#foo" class="clicko" id="2">Aliquilar</a>
  <a data-role="button" href="#foo" class="clicko" id="3">Busca</a>

    </p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Start of first page -->
     <div data-role="page" id="foo">
      <div data-role="header"> <a class="ui-btn ui-icon-carat-l ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all" data-direction="reverse" href="#page1">Back to page "one"</a>

        <h1 id="pagem"></h1>

           </div>
          <!-- /header -->
       <div>
    <input type="text" name="one"/>
    <input type="text" name="two"/>

           </div>
       <!-- /content -->
         <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>

         </div>
           <!-- /footer -->
           </div>
```

In this i am facing two problem.

1.When i click on venta or aliquler or buscar its changing header depending on that.But the problem is when i refresh the page(in jsfiddle result frame) the header is not displaying.
How can i make it as appear.

2.How can i display first input type if header is "venta". Otherwise it should display second input type.

Comment: what server side language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your question title is misleading, your questions don't have anything to do with it. Now let me answer your questions.

1. This is almost impossible, during full page refresh page is removed from the DOM and added again, nothing can survive such action. If nothing can survive there's no way for newly refreshed application to know what was last opened page.

   Thou there's one solution. Each time you change the page you can store current header into localstorage. If you more back to main page then remove this data. This way if page is refreshed application can still access localstorage to get last visited page.

   **[Read](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)** more about localstoare here and how it can be used. Unlike other page to page data transfer solutions, localstorage will persist even if device is turned off. Basically it is saved just like cookie, but unlike cookie it can hold large amount of data.
2. This is an easy implementation

   Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/YLhvc/

   ```
   $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#foo', function(){ 
       var headerName = $(this).find('.ui-header h1').text();
       switch (headerName) {
           case "Venta":
               $('#one').show();
               $('#two').hide();
               break;
           case "Alquiler":
               $('#one').hide();
               $('#two').show();
               break;
           case "Busca":
               $('#one').hide();
               $('#two').show();
               break;            
       }
   });
   ```

   As you can see, each time we change a page JavaScript will check current page header. Depending on it it will show/hide input elements.
3. And here's a solution that combines previous two.

   Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/rQz6g/

   #### HTML:

   ```
   <div data-role="page" id="page1">
       <div data-role="header">
           <h1>Click</h1>

       </div>
       <!-- /header -->
       <div role="main" class="ui-content">
           <p> <a data-role="button" href="#foo" class="clicko" id="1" data-header="Venta">Venta</a>
               <a data-role="button" href="#foo" class="clicko" id="2" data-header="Aliquilar">Aliquilar</a>
               <a data-role="button" href="#foo" class="clicko" id="3" data-header="Busca">Busca</a>
           </p>
       </div>
   </div>
   <!-- Start of first page -->
   <div data-role="page" id="foo">
       <div data-role="header"> <a class="ui-btn ui-icon-carat-l ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all" data-direction="reverse" href="#page1">Back to page "one"</a>

           <h1 id="pagem"></h1>

       </div>
       <!-- /header -->
       <div>
           <input type="text" name="one" id="one" style="display:none;" value="One"/>
           <input type="text" name="two" id="two" style="display:none;" value="Two"/>

       </div>
       <!-- /content -->
       <div data-role="footer">
           <h4>Page Footer</h4>

       </div>
       <!-- /footer -->
   </div>
   ```

   #### JavaScript:

   ```
   $('.clicko').on('click', function () {
       var headerTitle = $(this).data('header');
       localStorage.setItem("header", headerTitle);      
   });

   $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#foo', function(){ 
       var headerTitle = localStorage.getItem("header");
       $(this).find('.ui-header h1').html(headerTitle);
       switch (headerTitle) {
           case "Venta":
               $('#one').show();
               $('#two').hide();
               break;
           case "Alquiler":
               $('#one').hide();
               $('#two').show();
               break;
           case "Busca":
               $('#one').hide();
               $('#two').show();
               break;            
       }
   });
   ```